# Where are the quotes in Civilization: Beyond Earth from?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

In Civilization V, the quotes in the popup window appearing when researching a technology was finished, were from history's famous people like Einstein etc.

In Civ: BE, the quotes are like

> -Hutama, We are All Destined to Prosper

I haven't heard of any of the quote's authors. Where do the quotes come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quotes are from characters from Beyond Earth's fictional history, mostly from leaders of the playable civilizations.

For example, [Hutama is the leader of Polystralia](https://www.civilization.com/en/news/2014-09-a-candid-interview-with-polystralias-hutama/).

Comment: Many of them are "spacified" versions of folklore as well. For example, John Henry faces off against the Crawler instead of a Steam engine. 

*"John Henry smiled at the Crawler and he said: ' Sure, you can move a lot of dirt, but let's see who gets to to the Mohorovicic discontinuity first.' And he picked up his shovel and waited for the starting us.
— The Uncle Nevercloned Stories"*

Comment: A fairly comprehensive list can be found here: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Quotes/CivilizationBeyondEarth

Answer (score 2):

Some, like the "Uncle Nevercloned" stories, seem to be an adaptation of old Native American and African American stories. Uncle Nevercloned might be a reference to [Uncle Remus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Remus) and [Coyote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coyote_(mythology)) is a Native American mythological character.

Answer (score 0):

They are mostly made up from the playable characters history's.